# Split pandas dataframe column into 2 by regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like this and I want to split the name column into 2 columns where the Name column is overwritten as 'name and surname' and the 'middle name' column only contains the middle name, including the brackets.

```
In [1]: dd = {'Name' : ['Daniel [Jack] Horn', 'Marcus [Martin] Dwell', 'Greg [Alex] Waltz']}

In [2]: dd_frame = pd.DataFrame(dd)

In [3]: dd_frame
Out[3]: 
                    Name
0     Daniel [Jack] Horn
1  Marcus [Martin] Dwell
2      Greg [Alex] Waltz
```

The expected output is

```
             Name    MiddleName
0     Daniel Horn        [Jack]  
1    Marcus Dwell      [Martin]
2      Greg Waltz        [Alex]
```

What would be a simple way to do this without splitting into 3 columns and merging the 1st and 3rd?

Comment: If any of the answer helps. Close the answer by accepting that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using regex:

```
df = dd_frame
df['Middle Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r"\[(.*)\]")
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace(r"\s+\[(.*)\]", "")
```

---

```
    Name            Middle Name
0   Daniel Horn     Jack
1   Marcus Dwell    Martin
2   Greg Waltz      Alex
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df["Middle Name"] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[1][1:-1])


                Name      Middle Name
0   Daniel [Jack] Horn       Jack
1   Marcus [Martin] Dwell   Martin
2   Greg [Alex] Waltz        Alex
```

By far the worst way to do what you want but it works...  First it splits your name on `" "` (space). Then the middle item of the list, is your name. Then we take whats in between the brackets. If you want to keep the brackets, remove the `[1:-1]`

```
df["Midname"] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r'\[[^\]]*\]',x)[0])

#output

          Name           Middle Name    MidName
0   Daniel [Jack] Horn      Jack        [Jack]
1   Marcus [Martin] Dwell   Martin      [Martin]
2   Greg [Alex] Waltz       Alex        [Alex]
```

This is using regex, however, I am not an expert in Regex. `findall`, gathers your answers between brackets, therefore, you have to take the first element in that list to avoid having `[[Jack]]`

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the  excellent answers, using [string.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) :

```
extracts = [(f"{first}{last}", middle)
             for first, middle, last in 
             dd_frame.Name.str.split("(\[.+\])")]

pd.DataFrame(extracts, columns=["Name", "MiddleName"])

        Name      MiddleName
0   Daniel Horn      [Jack]
1   Marcus Dwell    [Martin]
2   Greg Waltz      [Alex]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it!

```
split = dd_frame['name'].split()
dd_frame['name'] = split[0] + split[1]
dd_frame['MiddleName'] = split[1]
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to split into 3 parts. He has mentioned in the question itself.